# Infinite loop with string to int converter

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, codeblocks

I am currently coding a small programm which will be used to compute the distance between two cities given their geographical coordinates (latitude and longitude) (kind of the same way Google Maps does, I think) but only for a limited number of cities.

My program gets the city's name, latitude and longitude with a getline in a file text. For instance, Paris will be "paris 48.51.12 2.20.5".

Then, I parse the line to get a)the name, b)the latitude (which is entered as angle.minutes.seconds), and c) the longitude. I parse latitude and longitude to have a vector with the 3 corresponding number but saved as strings.

Next step is to convert a vector of string into a vector of int. I've found a pretty neat method :

```
int strtoint(string str)
{
    int i=0;
    if(!(istringstream(str)>>i)) i=0;
    return i;
}
```

As for why I don't use *stoi* or *atoi*, I cannot get my compiler (MingW, in Code::Blocks 13.12) to understand them, so maybe I've missed a step.

However, when I try to use it with my vector, it goes into an infinite loop, and I don't understand why :

```
for(int unsigned i=0; i<latitude.size();i++)
{
    cout<<latitude[i]<<endl;
    i_latitude[i]=strtoint(latitude[i]);
}
```

With latitude being the string vector and i_latitude the int vector.

The following works for me :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

int strtoint(string str)
{
    int i=0;
    if(!(istringstream(str)>>i)) i=0;
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    string str="45";
    int nbr=strtoint(str);
    cout<<nbr<<endl<<endl; //shall return 45 as an integer

    string foo [3]= {"45", "32", "15"};
    int ifoo [3];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        ifoo[i]=strtoint(foo[i]);
        cout<<ifoo[i]<<endl; //shall return 45 32 15
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[edit : add of example]

Comment: Please include [mcve]. Just using your code, and filling in the blanks as I see fit, I could not [reproduce your problem](https://ideone.com/bGqLbA).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I've edited the question, hope this helps. Actually the test I provide runs perfectly for me, so I really don't understand why the infinite loop with the vector. Maybe there is a problem with getting the size of the vector ? But if so, what's the point of it being dynamic ?

Comment: It's more useful if you post a complete example that *doesn't* work.

Comment: @molbdnilo , well, the code in the question didn't work. Anyway, I think that the problem was me using i_latitude[i]=strtoint(latitude[i]); instead of i_latitude.push_back( strtoint(latitude[i]) ); .

Comment: Out of range error - second most common bug in the world.  Build and run a debug configuration first, so that you get range checking. In general, avoid using "i", let the compiler look after indexing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using c++11

```
for( auto& s : latitude )
{
  cout<<s<<endl;
  i_latitude.push_back( strtoint(s) );
}
```

You should use reference to avoid doing a string copy

```
int strtoint( const string & str)
{ ...
```

Comment: This "answer" is only about good coding practices, and not about the actual problem the OP is facing. Any "answer" at this stage is only a speculation, since the problem OP described, is not reproducible with information he has given us.

Comment: Actually, your answer solves my problem, thanks. I still don't get why it occured in the first place, so if you have any idea to help me understand it, I will gladly accept it !

Comment: The code you posted would work.  Obviously, the code you posted is not the same as the code that goes into an infinite loop.  Probably, you forgot to increment the loop variable ( i ).  This is the most common coding error in the world.  This is why you should use the C++ for loop.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius  good coding practices help to avoid problems like this.  It's why they are good.

Comment: I increment the variable in the for definition 'for(i=0;i<vector.size();i++)'

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me to find my mistake !